# is there a method to detect person and associate a text?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, spacy, tal

I have a text like :

> Take a loot at some of the first confirmed Forum speakers:  **John
> Sequiera**  Graduated in Biology at Facultad de Ciencias Exactas y
> Naturales,University of Buenos Aires, Argentina. In 2004 obtained a
> PhD in Biology (Molecular Neuroscience), at University of Buenos
> Aires, mentored by Prof. Marcelo Rubinstein. Between 2005 and 2008
> pursued postdoctoral training at Pasteur Institute (Paris) mentored by
> Prof Jean-Pierre Changeux, to investigate the role of nicotinic
> receptors in executive behaviors. Motivated by a deep interest in
> investigating human neurological diseases, in 2009 joined the
> Institute of Psychiatry at King’s College London where she performed
> basic research with a translational perspective in the field of
> neurodegeneration.
> Since 2016 has been chief of instructors / Adjunct professor at University of Buenos Aires, Facultad de Ciencias Exactas y Naturales.
> **Tom Gonzalez** is a professor of Neuroscience at the Sussex Neuroscience, School of Life Sciences, University of Sussex. Prof.
> Baden studies how neurons and networks compute, using the beautiful
> collection of circuits that make up the vertebrate retina as a model.

I want to have in output :
`[{"person" : "John Sequiera" , "content": "Graduated in Biology at Facultad...."},{"person" : "Tom Gonzalez" , "content": "is a professor of Neuroscience at the Sussex..."}]`

so we want to get NER : PER for person and in content we put all contents after detecting person until we found a new person in the text ...

it is possible ?

i try to use spacy to extract NER , but i found a difficulty to get content :

```
import spacy
​
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")
doc = nlp(text)
​
for ent in doc.ents:
    print(ent.text,ent.label_)
```

Comment: I am not sure why you want this, but each `ent` has an `end_char` attribute you can use to index into the original text.

Comment: You might be interested also in relation extraction rather than just position-based unselective context retrieval. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8HL-Ap5_Axo